# How to make rosmake and distcc work together

Tags: raspberrypi, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have setup a cross compiling environment to build ROS for [RaspberryPi](http://www.raspberrypi.org) using [distcc](http://code.google.com/p/distcc/). Everything works fine with cmake and I have successfully built parts of ros. However, in the [Debian install instructions](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Debian) when you get to Layer2 step 1.5, you issue:

```
rosmake -a
```

However, this doesn't call distcc. I have even tried:

```
CC="distcc arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc" CXX="distcc arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-g++" rosmake -a
```

with no success.

Any suggestions to get distcc and rosmake to work together? Again ... my setup does work fine with just cmake. Issueing:

```
CC="distcc arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc" CXX="distcc arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-g++" cmake .
```

inside a ros package works fine.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46987/how-to-make-rosmake-and-distcc-work-together/) by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2962 on 2012-10-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I might have asked too soon. I had to set the env on the raspberry pi to:

```
export DISTCC_HOSTS=arch
```

where *arch* is my linux machine (x86 machine) doing the cross compiling. This is odd, because I already set *arch* in the ~/.distcc/hosts. It appears ROS needs the env set.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1